# collection_select not passing dropdown selected param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to pass a param based on what I choose in the drop down menu. For some reason, the only param being sent is "bag"=>{"id"=>"1"}} no matter what I choose in the drop down menu

here is my view code (@bags = current_user.bags)

```
<%= form_tag(update_default_bag_path, :method => :put) do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select :bag, :id, @bags, :id, :name, {} %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

No matter what I choose in the dropdown it always just passes the current_user's first bag as params[:bag][:id]. Any ideas on why the posted params isn't changing and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason this was happening was because  appeared twice in the code. Once before the select I was trying to change. So be sure to check your code (use inspect element) to search for "bag[id]" and make sure it doesn't appear somewhere else on the same page!